# What is the technical term for 'x' in 'for x...'

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I had the code...

```
list = ['Clemont', 'Albert', 'Shiro']
for x in range(len(list)):
    print(x)
```

...what would technical term for `x` be here? I'm assuming it's "iterate object" but maybe that's a misconception; if it's not a misconception, what is an iterate object?

Comment: "Loop variable" maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The formal name for `x` in that context is [**`target`**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), as illustrated by Python's language reference:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

...with `target_list` (and `target`) defined as:

```
target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target          ::=  identifier
                     | "(" target_list ")"
                     | "[" target_list "]"
                     | attributeref
                     | subscription
                     | slicing
                     | "*" target
```

If you'd like to know what a target can actually accept or be defined as, feel encouraged to peruse the documentation.  By most standard meanings, you're using some kind of simple identifier, like a variable name (in this case, `x`) to represent the target.

Comment: But the term `target` is used for the LHS in [any old assignment](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), it's not specific to a `for` loop.

Comment: @tobias_k:  That's right.  It's not specific to anything necessarily.  That *implies* that there's no special name for it, from the context of the grammar.

Comment: I disagree; this only means that the same syntax can be used for both. There might be a more specific term that can be used when discussing with others to make them understand what you are talking about.

Comment: What you've quoted is the grammar specification. `target_list` and `target` are grammatical elements, which are common to many different types of statements. All this is saying is that the syntax for a loop variable is the same as the syntax for the destination of an assignment.

Answer (score 3):

"Loop variable" is as technical as you can get.

There's no official name since officially it isn't any different than the Left Hand Side for assignment statments; same rules apply to the "loop" variables as they do for the assignment targets.

Calling it "loop variable" among any other Python developers will get your point across.

---

As for *"what is an iterate object?"*, you've probably mistaken the term with *iterable* or *iterator* which is what the for loop requires in order for it to work, a good break-down of those terms is already present [in another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's an "official" term for it, but I've seen it called *iteration variable* or *loop variable*. This is not specific to Python, it's common in many different languages.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=iteration%20variable%2C%20loop%20variable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Citeration%20variable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cloop%20variable%3B%2Cc0) finds more hits for *loop variable*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this suits your definition of a "technical term", but the expression "loop variable" is used in quite a few PEP documents, e.g. for [iterators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) and [generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), though there seems to be no PEP on the basic `for` loop itself.